# Prove the statement: If the columns of a matrix $U$ are eigenvectors of a matrix $A$, then $A$ is upper triangular matrix.

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Matrix $U$ is defined as $        \begin{bmatrix}
        a & b & c \\
        0 & d & e \\
        0 & 0 & f \\
        \end{bmatrix},a\cdot b\cdot c\cdot d\cdot e\cdot f\neq0$.

Is it possible to find the entries of $A$ if it is known that the columns of $U$ are it's eigenvectors?

Comment: Yes. Make a matrix $A$ with nine symbolic entries, whatever letters you like. Most of the gain is from finding values inside $A$ so that $AU$ is  upper triangular; I'm not sure how important the eigenvector condition will be, but it could.

Comment: @JendrikStelzner: The equation $abcdef\neq 0$ is a nice way to say that none of these numbers is equal to zero.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: this hint is for showing that $A$ is upper triangular, not for finding the entries of $A$.

---

Hint: by matrix multiplication, $A \begin{bmatrix}a\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$ is $a$ times the first column of $A$. Since we know $\begin{bmatrix}a\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$ is an eigenvector of $A$, we further know that $A \begin{bmatrix}a\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$ has all zero entries except the first entry. Similar reasoning will show that the 2nd column of $A$ has all zero entries except the first two, and so on, showing that $A$ is upper triangular.

Comment: it's a way to prove $U^{-1}$ is also upper triangular, and so is $A = U D U^{-1}$